# Can I call someone else's public function/contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain

Still new and learning. Forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Since all contracts are uploaded to the same blockchain, if I wanted, could I use someone else's public contract in my own front-end app?

Does it work that way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

There is a min answer length, but yes.

Hope it helps.